# Problem configuring Realm (mongodb) in react native with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, react-native, realm

What I'm trying to do is configure a Realm in React Native. I have a class defining the schema of the object I want to persist in realm/mongodb.

```
import {Realm, createRealmContext} from '@realm/react';
import { Configuration, ConfigurationWithSync } from 'realm';
import {appId} from "../atlasConfig.json";

const app = Realm.App.getApp(appId);
const { currentUser } = app;

export class Task extends Realm.Object {
    _id!: Realm.BSON.ObjectId;
    description!: string;
    isComplete!: boolean;
    createdAt!: Date;
    count!: number;
  
    static generate(description: string) {
      return {
        _id: new Realm.BSON.ObjectId(),
        description,
        isComplete: false,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        count: 0
      };
    }
  
    static schema = {
      name: 'Task',
      primaryKey: '_id',
      properties: {
        _id: 'objectId',
        description: 'string',
        isComplete: {type: 'bool', default: false},
        createdAt: 'date',
        count: 'int?'
      },
    };
  }
  
  const config: Configuration = {
    schema: [Task],
    schemaVersion: 0,
    onMigration: (oldRealm: Realm, newRealm: Realm) => {
      if (oldRealm.schemaVersion < 1){
        const oldObjects = oldRealm.objects(Task);
        const newObjects = newRealm.objects(Task);

        for(const index in oldObjects){
          const oldObject = oldObjects[index];
          const newObject = newObjects[index];
          if(oldObject.isComplete){
            newObject.count = 1010;
          } else {
            newObject.count = 2020;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
    sync : {
      flexible: true,
      onError: console.error,
      initialSubscriptions: {
        update: (subs: Realm.App.Sync.MutableSubscriptionSet, realm: Realm) => {
          subs.add(realm.objects('Task'));
        },
        rerunOnOpen: true
      }
    }
  };
  export const realmContext = createRealmContext(config);
```

What I'm having trouble with is creating the configuration for the Realm. I want to add the sync config in the realm config, but it doesn't seem to work. Before, I gave the sync config to the RealmProvider as a prop. It didn't give me any error but it didn't do what I wanted. That's why I thought it would be better to create the config in the Realm config directly.

The error I'm getting is in the "sync" config in the realm config I'm declaring in the class above. It says that it is missing the "user" property, but when I add this property, I don't know what value to give it because whatever I try, the user seems to be null at this point. I couldn't find anything that could help me anywhere. And in all the docs I found on MongoDB website, they use the "user" property without giving it any value.

Comment: Two things: when you say *user* do you mean *UserProvider*? If you mean user, when does it not have a value? Here's how it would normally be defined within a `sync` property:  `user: app.currentUser` Also, I see a migration block but that may not work with Sync.

Comment: That's what I tried, but it says that `app.currentUser` might be null (`Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User<DefaultFunctionsFactory, SimpleObject, DefaultUserProfileData>' `). And why would migration not work with sync?

Comment: Just mentioned "may" as it's something to be aware of: *Synced realms only support non-breaking - also called additive - changes to ensure that older clients can sync with newer clients. Because full renames require you to delete the old property, you cannot rename a synchronized property without requiring a client reset.*

Comment: The sync property needs to include the user and partition value - that's what's missing from the code in the question. It would help us to help you if the current code (matching the doc) was included in the question, and then specify where things are not working. e.g. If I use code that matches the documentation, it works, but the current code in the question doesn't match. Let's see some updated code and we'll try to spot the issue.